# Powershell - Set parameter optional and let other params be at its position (0)

Tags: powershell

How to make a parameter optional but if the first param `($options)` isn't specified, then use next param `($controller_id)` at position 0.

The use case of param `$option` is very limited. I don't want to use two different script for just providing `$options` and then another script for `$controller_id.$objects`

Is this possible?

The script gets called in 2 ways. First time it'll call with `$options` (every 1 hour). Then every 5 minutes the script gets called with `$controller_id` and `$object`.

During the every 5 minutes script call, the `$options` won't be specified and only `$controller_id` and `$object` is specified. That is why I want the script to work fine when `$options` isn't specified

```
param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)]
   [ValidateSet( 'Controllers', 'test1')]
   [String]$options = $null,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)]
   [String]$controller_id,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
   [String]$object
)

if ($options -eq "Controllers") {
   callfunction1
}
else if ($options -eq "test1") {
   callfunction2
}
else if ( ($controller_id) -and $object -eq "something") {
    callsomething.$object | where {$_ -eq "$controller_id" }
}
```

Comment: It may not be possible by setting two parameters to position 0. If you must have this specific behavior, you could try using just one array parameter with the attribute ValueFromRemainingArguments, then parse what arguments come through.

A better solution would be to simply name the parameters when you call it, as these two example calls:
`myscript.ps1 -controller_id "the-id"; 
myscript.ps1 -options "Controllers" -controller_id "the-id"`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script the `ValidateSet` is not needed since you accept any string in the **controller_id** parameter.

Instead you might want to look at work arounds like changing how your `If` statement is set up

Here is a example

```
Function Test{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [String]$options,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
        [object]$object = $null
    )

    if ($object -ne $null) {
        "callsomething.$object | where {$_ -eq ""$options""}"
    }
    elseif ($options -eq "test1") {
       "callfunction2"
    }
    elseif ($options -eq "Controllers") {
       "callfunction1"
    }else{
        throw "You must choose between Controllers or test1"
    }
}

#Lets run some Tests

Test "Controllers"

Test "test1"

Test "Controllers" "ABC"

Test "test1" "adw"
```

And the results

```
callfunction1
callfunction2
callsomething.ABC | where { -eq "Controllers"}
callsomething.adw | where { -eq "test1"}
```

Comment: I'll test this shortly. But I want to mention that if `$options` isn't provided that means we'll be using `$controller_id and $object`. The script gets called in 2 ways. First time it'll call with `$options` (every 1 hour). Then every 5 minutes the script gets called with `$controller_id and $object`.

Comment: During the every 5 minutes script call, the `$options` won't be specified and only `$controller_id and $object ` is specified. That is why I want the script to work fine when `$options` isn't specified.

Comment: Well this script does take care of that. Second i have added error handling